# Need to change the color of individual on/off buttons on my page after being clicked from green to red

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several buttons on my webpage, each button is an option to have on or off, so by default they will be green (on), but after being clicked I want them to be red (off). I was able to get this to sort of work, but only one button changes color regardless of the button I click on. Here is my code

```css
  function toggleButton() {
    var element = document.getElementById("btn");
    element.classList.toggle("btn-off");
  }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="key">
      <button id="btn" class="option-btn" onclick="toggleButton()">A</button>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <button id="btn" class="option-btn" onclick="toggleButton()">B</button>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <button id="btn" class="option-btn" onclick="toggleButton()">C</button>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <button id="btn" class="option-btn" onclick="toggleButton()">D</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and then in my CSS I have the 'btn-off' class colored red.

This only works for the first button. If I click any other button, the first button still changes color. I know I can get this to work by giving each button a different id, and and writing a different function for each, but I'm hoping to avoid that repetition. Any tips/suggestions? (beginner developer here)

Comment: Each `id` must be unique in HTML. It's invalid to have two identical `id` attributes in the same document.

Comment: Have you ever try my answer below? Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
onclick="toggleButton()"
```

to

```
onclick="toggleButton(this)"
```

and then change your method to

```
function toggleButton(button) {
    button.classList.toggle("btn-off");
  }
```

Part of your issue is that you are repeating ids.  But for what you are doing, you don't need the ids if you pass in the element that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

please test the following code:

html

```
<body>
    <div class="color-red" id="test-div"></div>
    <button type="button" name="test" id="test" onclick="changeColor();">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

css

```
.color-red{
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.color-blue{
    background-color:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

js

```
function changeColor(){
    document.getElementById("test-div").classList.remove('color-red');
    document.getElementById("test-div").classList.add('color-blue');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited number of buttons you can choose the fast way:

HTML:

```
<div class="key">
  <button id="btn1" class="option-btn" onclick="toggleButton(1)">A</button>
</div>
<div class="key">
  <button id="btn2" class="option-btn" onclick="toggleButton(2)">B</button>
</div>
<div class="key">
  <button id="btn3" class="option-btn" onclick="toggleButton(3)">C</button>
</div>
<div class="key">
  <button id="btn4" class="option-btn" onclick="toggleButton(4)">D</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
  function toggleButton(n) {
    var element = document.getElementById('btn' + n);
    element.style.color = 'red'; //OR YOUR TOGGLE CLASS
  }
```

But if you have a large number of buttons, you should create the IDS dynamically in Javascript and take the **clicked button id** to change its color.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this on `jQuery` and this will fix your problem. Thanks

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".option-btn").on("click",function(){
      if($(this).hasClass("btn-off")){
          $(this).addClass("btn-on");
          $(this).removeClass("btn-off");
      }else{
          $(this).removeClass("btn-on");
          $(this).addClass("btn-off");
      }
    });
 });
```

```css
.btn-off{
    background-color:#EFF0F1;
}
.btn-on{
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="key">
      <button id="btn" class="option-btn btn-off">A</button>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <button id="btn" class="option-btn btn-off">B</button>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <button id="btn" class="option-btn btn-off">C</button>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <button id="btn" class="option-btn btn-off">D</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way to approach it. You shouldn't have multiple duplicate `id` attributes, so I'm using a `toggle-button` class instead for targeting.

Each button starts with the `btn-on` class, since you mentioned you want them on by default. Clicking one will toggle that class. Without it, it falls back to the "off" state, styled red.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-on');
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle-button {
  background-color: red;
}
.toggle-button.btn-on {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="key">
    <button class="toggle-button option-btn btn-on">A</button>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <button class="toggle-button option-btn btn-on">B</button>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <button class="toggle-button option-btn btn-on">C</button>
  </div>
  <div class="key">
    <button class="toggle-button option-btn btn-on">D</button>
  </div>
</div>
```